# Retrieve list of instance methods that are defined in rails class excluding inherited and included methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, mixins, activesupport

I have a class Product in my rails project, I am trying to retrieve a list of instance methods of my class that are defined in my file (not inherited method or included via mixin). Here's a small sample of my class :

```
class Product
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip
  include Mongoid::Search
  include Mongoid::Slug
  include Mongoid::Timestamps
  extend Enumerize
    def product_image
    image.url(:small) unless image.nil?
  end

  def product_school_level
    self.school_levels.join ' | '
  end

  def product_grades
    self.grades.where(degree_ids: nil).pluck(:name).uniq.join ' | '
  end
end
```

I tried to use  `Product.instance_methods(false)`. However this still returns a lot of methods I dont need, here's a little sample : 
:_run_post_process_callbacks,
 :aliased_fields,
 :_post_process_callbacks,
 :_run_image_post_process_callbacks,
 :_image_post_process_callbacks,
 :_validation_callbacks,
 :nested_attributes?,
 :_run_touch_callbacks,
 :readonly_attributes?,
 :_run_save_callbacks,
 :aliased_fields?,
 :_save_callbacks,
 :localized_fields?,
 :readonly_attributes,
 :fields?,
 :pre_processed_defaults?,
 :_update_callbacks,
 :post_processed_defaults?,
 :fields,
 :**_id_default**

I ran `Product.new.method(:_run_post_process_callbacks).source_location` on a few of these methods to try to check where they come from. It seems they all come from active_support. 
I never included active_support in my class, so I guess classes in a rails project automatically include active_supports methods ? How is that possible without any inheritance syntax (<<) or include syntax ?
How can I then achieve what I want to do and get rid of these methods I dont need in my list ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many (most? all?) of those extra methods you are seeing are being created using `Module#define_method`. If you dig deep in the source for `active_support`, you'll see that. (You aren't directly including `active_support`, but it's being pulled in by one or more of the `Mongoid` modules.)

So these are in fact valid instance methods of your model class, which is why they are included in `instance_methods(false)`. Other methods that are defined "conventionally" in the mixins, such as `#freeze`, are reported by `instance_methods(true)`, but not by `instance_methods(false)`.

I think you may have to do something to filter the list based on the source location. Something along these lines:

```
my_methods = Product.instance_methods(false).select do |m|
  Product.instance_method(m).source_location.first.ends_with? '/product.rb'
end
```

Comment: I dont understand your explication about Module#define_method : https://apidock.com/ruby/Module/define_method. I have checked it, and actually when you use define_method in a Parent class or in a module that is mixed in later, then the method is not returned by ```Child.instance_methods(false)```

Comment: @DavidGeismar. Yes, `define_method` can be used to define a method in the including class. Here's an example of how it can be done: https://gist.github.com/showaltb/da9e8773211f9e7b62d2a52ec2047eb2. (This isn't the exact technique `active_support` is using, but the effect is the same.)